# Storing user only in mongo db if condition from webflux mono is true in kotlin

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have the following question. I want to save a user into a mongo db via reactive spring data repositories only if the e-mail of the user is not already present.

```java
@Component("userService")
class UserService(private val repository: UserRepository){

        fun checkIfEMailExists(email: String): Mono<Boolean> {
                return repository.findByEMail(email).hasElement()
        }

        fun create(user: User): Mono<User> {
               //not sure how to do this bit here
               this.checkIfEMailExists(user.email)
               .filter{ it -> it == true}
               .map{repository.save(user)}  
        }  

}
```

So, basically I am not sure how i can handle the Mono of boolean to do something only if it's value is true (and otherwise thrown an exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your MongoDB repository should be a reactive one and return a `Mono<User>` or `Flux<User>` for that kind of signature:

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {

    Mono<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Then you can chain that reactive type with other operators like this:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Mono<User> create(User user) {
        return this.userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
                .flatMap(existingUser -> Mono.error(new UserAlreadyPresentException(existingUser.getEmail())))
                .then(this.userRepository.save(user));
    }

    class UserAlreadyPresentException extends RuntimeException {

        public UserAlreadyPresentException(String email) {
            super("User already present with email " + email);
        }
    }
}
```